# Finding a bijective function from an interval to a cartesian product.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

So yesterday i had this question in a test:

> Find a bijective function from $A:= (0,1]$ to $B:= (0,1] \times \mathbb{N}$, and prove it is indeed bijective.

All i had in mind is the idea that the function will probably need to split into two different sections from the domain in order to keep it injective and surjective, but most of my attempts were one to one but not onto.
Therefore I'll be glad for any guidance or hints trying to get it right in order to improve. Thank you!

Comment: Do you know a bijective function $(0, 1] \to (0, \infty)$? Or to any infinite interval?  That might be a useful start.

Comment: I know of:
$f: (0,1] \to [1,\infty)\\f(x)=\frac{1}{x}\\$
Which is bijective.

Comment: I dont think that "a bijective function $(0, 1] \to (0, \infty)$" is of any use. Instead, consider for instance $A=\sqcup_{n\in\Bbb N}(\frac1{n+1},\frac1n].$

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + [please avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: a bijective function $(0, 1] \to (0, \infty)$ is definitely useful here!  You can split $(0, \infty)$ into $(0, 1] \sqcup (1, 2] \sqcup (2, 3] \sqcup \cdots$

Answer (score 1):

Turning the problem around, splitting it into three problems and thinking about it geometrically can help. Although this solution this solution is very tedious, I'll present it to have an example of an explicit bijection. I am quite certain however that there are more direct ways to construct a bijection.

1. We are going to construct a bijection $$\varphi: (0,1] \times \mathbb{N} \to (0,1]$$ as a composition of three other bijections:
   $$\varphi = \psi_2 \circ \psi_1 \circ \theta,$$
   where
   $$ (0,1] \times \mathbb{N} \xrightarrow{\theta} (0,\infty) \xrightarrow{\psi_1} (0,1) \xrightarrow{\psi_2} (0,1].$$
2. What could $\theta$ look like? Think about $(0,1]\times \mathbb{N}$ as "$\mathbb{N}$ copies of the interval $(0,1]$ laying above each other". Now take these $\mathbb{N}$ copies and place them flush next to each other. What we get is half the real line, i.e. $(0,\infty)$. As a concrete function, this is $$\theta(x,n)=x+n.$$ Show rigorously that this is indeed a bijection.
3. For $\psi_1$, take a smooth function that is strictly monotone decreasing, starting at $1$ for $x=0$ and having the $x$-axis as asymptote. One that comes to my mind is $\psi(x)=e^{-x}$ (or any other base). Proof again rigorously that this is indeed a bijection.
4. For $\psi_2$, we can take for example $$\psi_2(x)= \begin{cases} x & \text{if }x \in (0,1)\setminus\{\frac{1}{2^n}\ | \ n \in \mathbb{N}\} \\ \frac{1}{2^{n-1}} & \text{if } n=\frac{1}{2^n} \text{ for some } n\in \mathbb{N} \end{cases}$$
5. Use the fact that the composition of bijections is itself a bijection to conclude that $\varphi = \psi_2 \circ \psi_1 \circ \theta$ is a bijection from $B$ to $A$.

Comment: Your $\psi$ is a bijection between $(0,\infty)$ and $(0,1)$, not between $(0,\infty)$ and $(0,1]$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!, in the last segment of you answer the output of the final inverse function is a number instead of a Cartesian product.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the mistakes! I fixed them in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\psi  :A \rightarrow B$ defined for every $x \in (0,1]$ by
$$\psi(x)=\left(\left\lfloor \dfrac{1}{x} \right\rfloor, 1- \left\lbrace \dfrac{1}{x} \right\rbrace \right)$$

where $\lfloor.\rfloor$ and $\lbrace.\rbrace$ denotes the functions integer part and fractional part respectively.

Let also $\varphi : B\rightarrow A$ defined for every $(k,x) \in \mathbb{N} \times (0,1]$ by
$$\varphi(k,x)=\dfrac{1}{k+1-x}$$

One can easily prove that $\psi$ and $\varphi$ are well-defined and that $\varphi \circ \psi = \mathrm{Id}_A$ and $\psi \circ \varphi = \mathrm{Id}_B$, therefore, they are bijections between $A$ and $B$.